# function getDoctrine won't work in one specific function of a controller

Tags: php, symfony, controller, doctrine

EDIT: now trying to use an EventSubscriber as b.enoit.be advised me. But when I send a mail, nothing happens. I don't get any error, but the mail isn't stored in my database either. And I tested What did I do wrong?

SentMailsListener.php:

```
<?php

namespace Fidelise\SignUpBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Fidelise\SignUpBundle\Entity\EmailsHistory;
use Swift_Events_SendEvent;

class SentMailsListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [Swift_Events_SendEvent::RESULT_SUCCESS => 'onMailSent'];
    }

    public function onMailSent(Swift_Events_SendEvent $event)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $message = $event->getMessage();
        $email = new EmailsHistory();
        $email->setRecipient(key($message->getTo()));
        $email->setSubject($message->getSubject());
        $email->setBody($message->getBody());
        $email->setSender(key($message->getFrom()));
        $em->persist($email);
        $em->flush();
    }
}
```

services.yml:

```
services:
    mail_sent_subscriber:
        class: Fidelise\SignUpBundle\EventListener\SentMailsListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

Comment: I would say we need more context in here. How is that method called?
`getDoctrine` is behind the scene, in the ControllerTrait, using the service locator, the the failling `has()` must be the one on `$this->container`. I would higly doubt the container is set on the Controller for all the rest but this function, but it might come from an odd way of dependency injecting it... So without further context, that would be hard to help you here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I added some extra code in my post, hope it helps. I can add some more if needed.

Comment: So yes indeed, your issue is coming from the fact that you are calling a function in your controller but not coming from the routing, so your dependency is not injected.

Comment: And really, did you mess into a actual existing dependency installed by composer? Eeeew :s

Comment: Okay thanks for your input, do you know how I can fix that dependency problem? And yeah I did mess into that, because I figured it would be the fastest way to call my "storeEmail" function whenever a mail is sent. If I have to manually call this function everytime after the "send" function from swift is called, i'm going to have to edit dozens of files.

Comment: "I figured it would be the fastest way to call my "storeEmail"" faster but totally hideous and impossible to deploy, when from what I see in Swift, they tend to dispatch a `Swift_Events_SendEvent` when a mail is actually send. So you'd be better using a EventSubscriber in order to do this.

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll try to do it that way then

Comment: I can't get it to work. I edited my post with the new files. Could you please tell me what I did wrong? @b.enoit.be

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your driver extends from `AbstractController`. Anyway, without more code, it is difficult to give you a concrete answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've edited my post and added some code. As you can now see, my IndexController class extends Controller. Does it need to extend AbstractController (I don't even have that class in my project)? Because every single other "getDoctrine" function called in that file work perfectly without that, so it's kind of confusing to me.